# How to populate the textbox using while loop and onchange function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used the while loop to populate the textbox component using onchange jquery function. but i am unable to return the value 5 for each 5 component using jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#fname').change(function () {
        var tot_row = 5;
        var row = 0;

        while (row < tot_row) {
            var math_marks = eval('get_math_marks_' + row + '_value()');
            var eng_marks = eval('get_eng_marks_' + row + '_value()');
            var variance_marks = math_marks - eng_marks;

            var component_to_be_replaced = 'variance_' + row;

            $("#component_to_be_replaced").val("5");
            row++;
        }
    });
});
```

I have been using the iframe.

Comment: I wish I can do a message.toLowercase()

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
$("#component_to_be_replaced").val("5");
```

to

```
$("#" + component_to_be_replaced).val("5");
```

It shouldn't be a string literal.